# Looking for a key-value database that is not in-memory, and have "list,set" datatypes

Tags: database, nosql, redis, key-value, key-value-store

I am using redis to store highly requested info, but I want to store less-requested stuff in a list/set on the disk. I have been looking around with no luck. Memcached, Riak etc. don't seem to have list/set datatypes. Is there a database that have those features?

Thanks.

Comment: You can probably throw something together using files holding JSON stringified objects in ~100 lines of PHP. /storagedir/[key].json, get.php?key=[key]. [key] can be the encoded URI Path to the resource or a GUID.

Comment: I need the database to have native lists/sets functions to manipulate them

Comment: Seems like a relational database (RDBMS) use-case to me. You could probably use SQLite.

Comment: even if the data set is very large?

Comment: FYI: [redisk](https://github.com/Moodstocks/redisk) is a disk-persistent Redis-compatible library that features list/set. Unfortunately: this project has been made within a 40-hour hackathon. In other words it is **NOT** stable at all (do not use it in production), and it is not finished (not all list/set manipulations commands are implemented). Keeping this in mind you may want to play with it (for the fun) until it gets finished (someday).

Comment: How large is the data you are keeping?  If it is large data you can keep an id reference to them in redis sets/lists and then retrieve them from a filestore/SQL/mongo/etc.  This would save a lot of memory unless your data is very small with a lot of keys.

Answer (score 2):

Run another Redis instance and configure it with AOF on.  Append-only file.

You can read more about it here:

http://redis.io/topics/persistence

Scroll half way down, there is alot of good information on it.

> **Append-only file** 
>   Snapshotting is not very durable. If your computer
>   running Redis stops, your power line fails, or you accidentally kill
>   -9 your instance, the latest data written on Redis will get lost. While this may not be a big deal for some applications, there are use
>   cases for full durability, and in these cases Redis was not a viable
>   option. The append-only file is an alternative, fully-durable strategy
>   for Redis. It became available in version 1.1. You can turn on the AOF
>   in your configuration file: appendonly yes From now on, every time
>   Redis receives a command that changes the dataset (e.g. SET) it will
>   append it to the AOF. When you restart Redis it will re-play the AOF
>   to rebuild the state.

Comment: thanks this is very useful. Don't you just love redis? For my case, I will go with using a relational database with indexing.